# Configure a select statement with multiple sum() statements to only output nonzero results

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Doing a pie chart in SRSS and i am trying to produce a proper sql query for it. Basically i am trying to analyze a table with files only opened in the last month. There is a Date_Opened field which i can use for this scenario:

```
SELECT count(*) AS NoOfFiles,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date_Opened) >= DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(m, 1, getdate()))
                  AND DATEPART(YEAR, Date_Opened) >= DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
                  AND Case_Category_ID = 225 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS InDischargeLoan,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, Date_Opened) >= DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(m, 1, getdate()))
                  AND DATEPART(YEAR, Date_Opened) >= DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
                  AND Case_Category_ID = 226 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS TechnicalDev,
FROM   dbo.Cases
```

The above query will add columns equal to zero. But i only want non zero columns. I think
using 'having' or group by might work but unsure how to use these commands?

Comment: Columns are fixed. You can't dynamically remove a column from a query result.

Comment: I think will have to create a temporary table using a loop and do my select from that?

Comment: Yes you could put the result of the `SELECT` into a temporary table then generate a dynamic SQL query containing only the columns you want. No idea if SSRS actually forces you to do that or not though.